# Error installing rugarch

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to install `rugarch package in Rstudio 3.3 (mac).

```
install.package("rugarch")
```

When I run `library(rugarch)` this is the error:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>     there is no package called 'truncnorm'
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rugarch'

someone knows how to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update R. From [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/truncnorm/index.html) you can see that `truncnorm` requires `R >= 3.4.0`:

> truncnorm: Truncated Normal Distribution
>   Density, probability, quantile and random number generation functions for the truncated normal distribution.
>
> Version:   1.0-8
>   Depends:    R (≥ 3.4.0)